# Identifying the difference in Two files in unix

Tags: bash, unix, awk, scripting, text-processing

> I have 2 files rec1.txt and rec2.txt.

```
[gpadmin@subh ~]$cat ret1.txt
emcas_fin_bi=324
emcas_fin_drr=3294
emcas_fin_exp=887
emcas_fin_optics=0
emcas_gbo_gs=3077
```

and

```
[gpadmin@subh ~]$ cat ret2.txt
emcas_fin_bi=333
emcas_fin_drr=5528
emcas_fin_exp=1134
emcas_fin_optics=0
emcas_fin_revpro=0
emcas_gbo_gs=3897
```

I am providing for compare as :-

```
[gpadmin@subh ~]$ diff -y ret1.txt ret2.txt
emcas_fin_bi=324                                 | emcas_fin_bi=333
emcas_fin_drr=3294                               | emcas_fin_drr=5528
emcas_fin_exp=887                                | emcas_fin_exp=1134
emcas_fin_optics=0                                 emcas_fin_optics=0
emcas_gbo_gs=3077                                | emcas_fin_revpro=0
                                                 > emcas_gbo_gs=3897
```

I see this is wrong output from above output since emcas_gbo_gs is common but showing as new word:-

```
emcas_gbo_gs=3077                                | emcas_fin_revpro=0
                                                 > emcas_gbo_gs=3897
```

Desired Output :-

```
emcas_gbo_gs=3077                                | emcas_gbo_gs=3897
                                                 > emcas_fin_revpro=0
```

Comment: your desired output and what you got are same except for the order, is the order important to you ????, kindly consider adding complete expected output

Comment: Yes @Inder, since my output is wrong, in the 2nd column emcas_gbo_gs match with the 1st column, but its showing as a new entry and matching with other emcas... which is wrong.

Comment: So you just want the unique values from both the files ??unique values based on whats before '=' ???

Comment: Okay... I will try to approach this another way... You can help me find the difference of the two files in 3rd file by subtracting the 2nd file with the 1st. But any new entry in 2nd file should also be captured in the final(3rd) file.

Comment: Do you really need the output to be formatted into columns the exact same way `diff` does?

Comment: @Charles, It will be helpful or you can help me with the one i commented before.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how the comment clarifies your question.

Comment: As because, the desired output is leading me to another logic which i am using for Subtracting.

Comment: @SubhashisDey can you please include the desired output in its entirety ? , it will be really helpful

Comment: Suppose:-
`emcas_fin_bi=9
emcas_fin_drr=2234
emcas_fin_exp=247
emcas_fin_optics=0
emcas_gbo_gs=820
emcas_fin_revpro=0`

Comment: Are you trying to compare line by line or name by name (where name is the part before the =)? You didn't show how to handle an entry that only appears in the first file.

Comment: @EdMorton name by name

Comment: Include in your sample input/output a "name" that only occurs in file1. Can the same name occur multiple times in 1 file?

Comment: Both file are generated from diff output. @karakfa already provided the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -F= 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2; next} 
           $1 in a {if(a[$1]!=$2) print $1 FS a[$1] "\t!" $0; 
                    delete a[$1]; next} 
                   {print " \t>" $0}  
               END {for(k in a) print ">" k"="a[k]}' f1 f2 | column -ts$'\t'

emcas_fin_bi=324    !emcas_fin_bi=333
emcas_fin_drr=3294  !emcas_fin_drr=5528
emcas_fin_exp=887   !emcas_fin_exp=1134
                    >emcas_fin_revpro=0
emcas_gbo_gs=3077   !emcas_gbo_gs=3897
```

Comment: you post one of the most scariest looking awk's I have ever seen :P

Comment: replace exclamation mark `!` with pipe and space `| `, old eyes can't see well anymore...

Comment: @Inder, each separate statement should be easy to understand.  Putting them together may need some experience but not analyzing it.

Comment: @karakfa, emcas_fin_optics=0 is missing after running your awk. Why?
Even  when i Run this awk with few more entries, i am unable to get all the output. Few are missing.

Comment: It's missing because it's the same in both files, so there is no difference.

Comment: @karakfa, Okay... I will try to approach this another way... You can help me find the difference of the two files in 3rd file by subtracting the 2nd file with the 1st. But any new entry in 2nd file should also be captured in the final(3rd) file.
Suppose:- `emcas_fin_bi=9
    emcas_fin_drr=2234 
    emcas_fin_exp=247 
emcas_fin_optics=0 emcas_gbo_gs=820 emcas_fin_revpro=0`

Comment: @karakfa, If there is no diff, can you still keep it side by side like others with `<black-space>` maybe (like ! and > you applied for the diff.).

Answer (score 0):

The `diff` tool compares **lines** not **(key)words**. And even the `--minimal` option did not yield your desired result (at least on my machine).

I see two solutions:

- Always add new keywords at the end of the file.
- Separate changes to values from adding (or deleting) keywords.

Comment: Okay... I will try to approach this another way... You can help me find the difference of the two files in 3rd file by subtracting the 2nd file with the 1st. But any new entry in 2nd file should also be captured in the final(3rd) file.